# How to merge methods with unrelated parameter types into one generic one?

Tags: java, c#, generics, grammar, syntactic-sugar

### For java/C#

There is my code:

```
class Room{
  HashSet tables;
  HashSet cups;

  void AddTable(Table table){ tables.Add(table); }
  void AddCup(Cup cup){ cups.Add(cup); }
  Table GetTable(){...}
  Cup GetCup(){...}
  ...
}
```

Can I merge `AddTable` and `AddCup` into one method like `Add<T>`

like this:

```
        void Add<T>(T t)
        {
            if (t is Table table) { ... }
            else if (t is Ground ground) { ... }
            ...
        }

        T Get<T>(){
            ...
        }
```

The problem is that there are too many `if else`.

Do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: Java and C# are different languages. You aren't writing your app in both. Which is it?

Comment: The point of a generic method is to do the same thing with an object regardless of its type. If you want to add different types of objects to different collections then you're not doing the same thing regardless of type, so this is not a job for generics. If you have to test the type at all in a generic method then it probably shouldn't be generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name the methods the same so that they will be overloads of each other:

```java
  void Add(Table table){ tables.Add(table); }
  void Add(Cup cup){ cups.Add(cup); }
```

The compiler is smart enough to call the correct method. (And Table and Cup are unrelated classes, so there are no caveats).

Comment: Thanks, I forget another problem. How to get it (with generic)? (Sorry :( )

Comment: Why would you want generics? You don't need them here, it works without.

Comment: I have many type to add/get, So I'm thinking if it can be simplified to a method.

Comment: You can't. As you have found out, you will have to switch on the type, so it is simpler to overload the method. Clients of your code can then simply call `Add(…)`